# Building Qt 5.15.2 using MinGW-64: Build Error (missing EGL/egl.h)

Tags: c++, qt, opengl-es, mingw

I have been trying to build Qt 5.15.2 for several days. I fixed several problems but I can not find much about this last error (Or outdated).

Configuration succeeded but build using mingw32-make command fails with this error:

> qwindowseglcontext.h: 45: 10: fatal error: EGL / egl.h: No such file or directory

I understand that it is missing a header, but I cannot find a viable explanation on how to correct this problem. After some research I came across https://cn.khronos.org/egl/ but the download link is dead, I also saw some people say that it would be possible using an OpenGL ES AMD SDK but I don't know what it really is.

If anyone could help me clear this up, that would be really appreciated. Thanks

Here is the list of arguments I use to configure Qt before compilation:

> ./configure.bat -skip qtimageformats -skip qtwinextras -no-feature-action -no-feature-animation -no-feature-big_codecs -no-feature-buttongroup -no-feature-calendarwidget -no-feature-codecs -no-feature-colordialog -no-feature-columnview -no-feature-combobox -no-feature-commandlinkbutton -no-feature-completer -no-feature-concatenatetablesproxymodel -no-feature-contextmenu -no-feature-cups -no-feature-cupsjobwidget -no-feature-datetimeedit -no-feature-dbus -no-feature-debug -no-feature-debug_and_release -no-feature-developer-build -no-feature-dial -no-feature-dirmodel -no-feature-dockwidget -no-feature-draganddrop -no-feature-easingcurve -no-feature-effects -no-feature-errormessage -no-feature-filedialog -feature-filesystemmodel -feature-filesystemwatcher -no-feature-fontcombobox -no-feature-fontdialog -no-feature-force_debug_info -no-feature-fscompleter -no-feature-gestures -no-feature-graphicseffect -no-feature-graphicsview -no-feature-groupbox -no-feature-hijricalendar -no-feature-iconv -no-feature-icu -no-feature-identityproxymodel -no-feature-im -no-feature-image_heuristic_mask -no-feature-image_text -no-feature-imageformat_bmp -no-feature-imageformat_jpeg -no-feature-imageformat_ppm -no-feature-imageformat_xbm -no-feature-inotify -no-feature-inputdialog -no-feature-islamiccivilcalendar -no-feature-itemviews -no-feature-jalalicalendar -no-feature-keysequenceedit -no-feature-lcdnumber -no-feature-lineedit -no-feature-listview -no-feature-listwidget -no-feature-mainwindow -no-feature-mdiarea -no-feature-menu -no-feature-menubar -no-feature-mimetype -no-feature-mimetype-database -no-feature-movie -no-feature-optimize_debug -feature-optimize_size -no-feature-pdf -no-feature-printdialog -no-feature-printer -no-feature-printpreviewdialog -no-feature-printpreviewwidget -no-feature-progressbar -no-feature-progressdialog -no-feature-proxymodel -no-feature-radiobutton -no-feature-raster-64bit -no-feature-release_tools -no-feature-resizehandler -no-feature-rubberband -no-feature-scrollarea -no-feature-scrollbar -no-feature-scroller -no-feature-separate_debug_info -no-feature-shared -no-feature-sizegrip -no-feature-slider -no-feature-sortfilterproxymodel -no-feature-spinbox -no-feature-splashscreen -no-feature-splitter -no-feature-stackedwidget -no-feature-standarditemmodel -no-feature-statemachine -feature-static -feature-static_runtime -no-feature-statusbar -no-feature-statustip -no-feature-stringlistmodel -no-feature-syntaxhighlighter -no-feature-systemtrayicon -no-feature-tabbar -no-feature-tabletevent -no-feature-tableview -no-feature-tablewidget -no-feature-tabwidget -no-feature-textbrowser -no-feature-textedit -no-feature-texthtmlparser -no-feature-textmarkdownreader -no-feature-textmarkdownwriter -no-feature-textodfwriter -no-feature-timezone -no-feature-toolbar -no-feature-toolbox -no-feature-toolbutton -no-feature-tooltip -no-feature-topleveldomain -no-feature-translation -no-feature-transposeproxymodel -no-feature-treeview -no-feature-treewidget -no-feature-undocommand -no-feature-undogroup -no-feature-undostack -no-feature-undoview -no-feature-validator -no-feature-whatsthis -no-feature-wheelevent -no-feature-widgettextcontrol -no-feature-wizard -confirm-license -nomake examples -nomake tests -nomake tools -opensource -platform win32-g++ -prefix "C:\Qt\Static\5.15.2"

This list comes with the project I want to use this Qt build for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use EGL from https://github.com/McNopper/EGL

Here's how I build and install it from MSYS2 so it works with Qt:

```sh
# change the install path below as needed
INSTALLPREFIX=/D/Prog/build

# fix missing egl.pc
cat > egl.pc << EOF
prefix=$INSTALLPREFIX
libdir=\${prefix}/lib
includedir=\${prefix}/include

Name: egl
Description: EGL implementation supporting OpenGL
Version: $VERSION
Libs: -L\${libdir} -legl
Cflags: -I\${includedir}
EOF
# fix EGL/CMakeLists.txt
patch -ulbf EGL/CMakeLists.txt << EOF
@@ -25,2 +25,5 @@
     \${EGL_SOURCES})
+add_library(egl_shared SHARED
+    \${EGL_SOURCES})
+set_target_properties(egl_shared PROPERTIES OUTPUT_NAME egl)

@@ -28,2 +31,4 @@
     \${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/include)
+target_include_directories(egl_shared PUBLIC
+    \${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/include)
 add_definitions(-DEGLAPI=)
EOF
mkdir -p build &&
 cmake.exe -Wno-dev -G"MSYS Makefiles" -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX:PATH=$INSTALLPREFIX -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE:STRING=Release -SEGL -Bbuild &&
 echo "-Wl,--as-needed -lopengl32 -lglew32" >> build/CMakeFiles/egl_shared.dir/linklibs.rsp &&
 make -Cbuild &&
 strip build/*.dll &&
 mkdir -p $INSTALLPREFIX/include $INSTALLPREFIX/lib/pkgconfig $INSTALLPREFIX/bin &&
 cp -rf EGL/include/* $INSTALLPREFIX/include/ &&
 cp -f build/lib*.a $INSTALLPREFIX/lib/ &&
 cp -f build/*.dll $INSTALLPREFIX/bin/ &&
 cp -f egl.pc $INSTALLPREFIX/lib/pkgconfig/ &&
 echo SUCCESS
```

The above depends on glew, which can be built from the sources at http://sourceforge.net/projects/glew/files/glew/ like this:

```sh
# change the install path below as needed
INSTALLPREFIX=/D/Prog/build

mkdir -p build_win &&
 cmake.exe -Wno-dev -GNinja -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX:PATH=$INSTALLPREFIX -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE:STRING=Release -DBUILD_UTILS:BOOL=ON -Sbuild/cmake -Bbuild_win &&
 ninja -Cbuild_win &&
 # manually build libglew32mx
 gcc -DGLEW_MX -O2 -Wall -W -Iinclude -DGLEW_BUILD -o src/glew.mx.o -c src/glew.c &&
 gcc -fno-builtin -fno-stack-protector -shared -s -Wl,-soname,libglew32mx.dll -Wl,--out-implib,lib/libglew32mx.dll.a -o lib/glew32mx.dll src/glew.mx.o -Wl,--as-needed -lglu32 -lopengl32 -lgdi32 -luser32 -lkernel32 -nostdlib &&
 ar cr lib/libglew32mx.a src/glew.mx.o &&
 ninja -Cbuild_win install/strip &&
 # manually install libglew32mx
 cp -f lib/libglew32mx*.a $INSTALLPREFIX/lib/ &&
 cp -f lib/glew32mx.dll $INSTALLPREFIX/bin/ &&
 sed -e "s/-lglew32/-lglew32mx/; s/^Cflags: /&-DGLEW_MX /" $INSTALLPREFIX/lib/pkgconfig/glew.pc > $INSTALLPREFIX/lib/pkgconfig/glewmx.pc &&
 # manually install where needed
 cp -f include/GL/eglew.h $INSTALLPREFIX/include/GL/ &&
 mkdir -p $INSTALLPREFIX/cmake &&
 cp -f build/cmake/*.cmake $INSTALLPREFIX/cmake/ &&
 cp -f build_win/CMakeFiles/Export/lib/cmake/glew/*.cmake $INSTALLPREFIX/cmake/ &&
 sed -i -z -e "s/\(get_filename_component(_IMPORT_PREFIX \"\${_IMPORT_PREFIX}\" PATH)\n\)\{3\}/\1/" $INSTALLPREFIX/cmake/glew-targets.cmake &&
 echo SUCCESS
```

Comment: First thanks for your help. I seen that the compilation need to include glew32, but i personally need to compile Qt staticly without any dll. There is a way to skip glew dll ? (Without breaking the EGL ?)

Comment: Why do you need to do without glew32? You can just link with static glew32...
I edited my answer with instructions for building glew.

Comment: Thanks for explanations. I tried a lot of time to use the commands that you provided to build and even after fixing dependencies problems like ninja or cmake on MSYS2, i can't move forward and compile it. First error was, C & CCX compilers not found, i gived it gcc path and after that still nothing. MSYS2 seems to be a quit mysterious for me

Comment: MSYS2 allows you to do a lot of stuff as if you were on Linux/Unix because it provides a bash shell. I see you try to build Qt with MinGW from a batch file. I never got that to work properly. If you still have issues finding the compilers, try to download a standalone compiler package from https://winlibs.com/, extract it and add it in front of the PATH variable. In MSYS this can be done with something like `export PATH=/d/Prog/winlibs64/mingw64/bin:$PATH`

Comment: I will try today to compile everything with MSVC compiler. It's generally less compliant but also less tricky results.

Also, do you know if the EGL that you provided require glew 1.12.0 or support 2.1.0 ?

(I don't really get how to compile everything with MinGW, glew seems build ready with MSVC)

Comment: I'm not a fan of MSVC, especially if it means runtime dependancies that need to be installed. But then again, I haven't used it in years... With MinGW-w64 I build EGL master from https://github.com/McNopper/EGL with dependancy glew 2.2.0 as explained above.

Comment: I would also prefer to use MinGW64 with the script you provided but unfortunately I can't get it to work properly.
I must be missing something ...

Comment: My script was really meant for an MSYS2 shell environment with the https://winlibs.com/ builds of MinGW-w64. It took me many years to get that environment perfectly tuned for reproducible builds...

Comment: I will try one more time to build with MSYS2

Comment: If Ninja doesn't work for you replace `-GNinja` with `-G"MSYS Makefiles"` and `ninja` with `make` in my script above.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by using the `-no-opengl` flag.

Here is my full `configure` list:

```
./configure -release -opensource -confirm-license -prefix ".\MinGW" -platform win32-g++ -nomake examples -nomake tests -no-opengl
```

Comment: That don't solve the problem, this is just a "bypass". By adding the -no-opengl flag, the staticly builded QT will miss a lot of needed features.